# traversing xtext ast from the project code

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext

I have a dsl grammar in xtext that I am using in my eclipse plugin.
in the plugin the user manually creates an new file (like the blog.dmodel file in https://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/102_domainmodelwalkthrough.html)

In my plugin code, when a user right clicks in the dmodel file, he can select from the right click menu an option that triggers a method called traverseAST()
This method currently finds the

```
    IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
    IProject project = root.getProject(projectName);
    IFolder folder = project.getFolder(path);
    IFile file = folder.getFile(fileName);
```

I understand that IFile is not what I can use to traverse the AST, so I am trying the following approach

```
    @Inject
    static ResourceSet resourceSet;
    public traverseAST(){
        IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
        IProject project = root.getProject(projectName);
        IFolder folder = project.getFolder(path);
        IFile file = folder.getFile(fileName);
        org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI uri = org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI.createPlatformResourceURI(file.getFullPath().toString(), true);
        ResourceSet set  = new ResourceSetImpl();
        Resource resource = set.createResource(uri);
        TreeIterator<Object> x1 = EcoreUtil.getAllContents(resource, true);
        TreeIterator<Object> x2 = EcoreUtil.getAllContents(resource, false);
}
```

My resource is `org.eclipse.xtext.linking.lazy.LazyLinkingResource@1230a38d uri='platform:/resource/demo/src/blog.dmodel'`

but both x1 and x2 are empty.

What am I doing wrong?

_____EDIT______
per Christian Dietrich suggestions my code is now

```
    IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
    IProject project = root.getProject(projectName);
    IFolder folder = project.getFolder(path);
    IFile file = folder.getFile(fileNameWithoutExtension + suffix);
    org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI uri = org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI.createPlatformResourceURI(file.getFullPath().toString(), true);
    IResourceSetProvider rs1 = IResourceServiceProvider.Registry.INSTANCE.getResourceServiceProvider(uri).get(IResourceSetProvider.class);
    ResourceSet rs = rs1.get(project);
    Resource r = rs.getResource(uri, true);
```

the `uri` value is

```
platform:/resource/demo/src/blog.dmodel
```

`rs1` is

```
org.eclipse.xtext.ui.resource.XtextResourceSetProvider@2faab150
FactoryProxy[key=Key[type=org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResourceSet, annotation=[none]], provider=com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory@6185cb4d]
```

`rs` is `org.eclipse.xtext.resource.SynchronizedXtextResourceSet@39fcefea resources=[org.eclipse.xtext.linking.lazy.LazyLinkingResource@25d48650 uri='platform:/resource/demo/src/blog.dmodel']`

r is

```
org.eclipse.xtext.linking.lazy.LazyLinkingResource@25d48650 uri='platform:/resource/demo/src/blog.dmodel'
```

but the content is `[]`

**EDIT 2_**

sharing more code per request.

my eclipse menu handler code 
BaseMenuHandler.java
    The following code is activated when the user is clicking on the option in the drop down menu. This is a standard addition of an option to an Eclipse menu
    static public class InsertEvents {
        @Override
        public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
                    IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
                    IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
                    Traverse.traverseAST(page, workspace);
       }

```
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspace;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.TreeIterator;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreUtil;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorInput;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorPart;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
import org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE;
import org.eclipse.xtext.resource.IResourceServiceProvider;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.resource.IResourceSetProvider;
public class Traverse{
    public static void traverseAST(IWorkbenchPage page, IWorkspace workspace) {
        IFile ifile = getSelectedIFile();
        if (ifile != null) {
            String fileName = ifile.getName();
            String fileNameWithoutExtension = fileName.replace(ifile.getFileExtension().toString(), "");
            String projectName = ifile.getProject().getName();
            String path = ifile.getProjectRelativePath().toString().replace("/" + fileName, "");
            IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
            IProject project = root.getProject(projectName);
            IFolder folder = project.getFolder(path);
            IFile file = folder.getFile(fileNameWithoutExtension + "dmodel");
            if (suffix.equals("dmodel")){
               String path1 = file.getFullPath().toString();
            org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI uri = org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI.createPlatformResourceURI(file.getFullPath().toString(), true);
            IResourceSetProvider rs1 = IResourceServiceProvider.Registry.INSTANCE.getResourceServiceProvider(uri).get(IResourceSetProvider.class);
            ResourceSet rs = rs1.get(project);
            Resource r = rs.getResource(uri, true);
            TreeIterator<Object> x1 = EcoreUtil.getAllContents(r, true);
            TreeIterator<Object> x2 = EcoreUtil.getAllContents(r, false);

}


        }
```

the blog.dmodel code is the 15 minutes tutorial without any changes from here:
https://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/102_domainmodelwalkthrough.html
____EDIT 3____
Following our conversation
I've created main under the xtext project (blog.mydsl)

```
package blog.mydsl;

import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.TreeIterator;
import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreUtil;
import org.example.domainmodel.DomainmodelStandaloneSetup;

import com.google.inject.Injector;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URI uri = URI.createURI("/Users/Desktop/demo.mydsl");
        Injector i = new DomainmodelStandaloneSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
        ResourceSet rs = i.getInstance(ResourceSet.class);
        Resource r = rs.getResource(uri, true);
        TreeIterator<Object> x1 = EcoreUtil.getAllContents(r, true);
        while (x1.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(x1.next());
        }
        TreeIterator<Object> x2 = EcoreUtil.getAllContents(r, false);
        while (x2.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(x2.next());
        }
    }

}
```

This seems to be working.
Since I did not do anything like the following
        Injector i = new DomainmodelStandaloneSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
in my original code, should this be the way to go?
should I move the plugin code to the blog.mydsl src folder?
should I look into the URI?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work.

```
@Inject
IResourceSetProvider resourceSetProvider;
...
URI uri = URI.createPlatformResourceURI(file.getFullPath().toString(), true);
ResourceSet rs = resourceSetProvider.get(project);
Resource r = rs.getResource(uri, true);
```

if you dont create your code via guice (`YourDslExecutableExtensionFactory`) you can obtain an `Injector` or the `IResourceSetProvider` via `IResourceServiceProvider.Registry.INSTANCE.getResourceServiceProvider(uri).get(IResourceSetProvider.class);`

update:

which the code you shared (i had to improvise a lot) it looks more like a debugging issue. see

```
org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI uri = org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI
    .createPlatformResourceURI(file.getFullPath().toString(), true);
IResourceSetProvider rs1 = IResourceServiceProvider.Registry.INSTANCE.getResourceServiceProvider(uri)
        .get(IResourceSetProvider.class);
ResourceSet rs = rs1.get(project);
Resource r = rs.getResource(uri, true);
TreeIterator<Object> x1 = EcoreUtil.getAllContents(r, true);
while(x1.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(x1.next());
}
TreeIterator<Object> x2 = EcoreUtil.getAllContents(r, false);
while(x2.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(x2.next());
}
```

Comment: I am still getting an empty tree iterator in x1 and x2. Updated my code with your suggestions, but not sure what am I doing wrong

Comment: Can you Share a completely runnable Demo

Comment: by demo you mean the blog.dmodel code or the java code for the eclipse plugin?

Comment: I want to be able to reproduce the problem thus your dsl plugins and a demo project

Comment: added more code, please let me know if I can add anything else?

Comment: i still cannot reproduce. maybe this is a eclipse debugger tooling problem (treeiterator.tostring) gives []

Comment: but even the             EList<Resource> l = rs.getResources();
 is empty

maybe the uri is wrong ?

Comment: So can you share code I can simply import and run eg a github or Gitlab repo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118336/discussion-between-quantico-and-christian-dietrich).

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: No standalone setup is not to be used inside eclipse

Comment: so what might be the issue?

Comment: And using the registry it should work in eclipse as well. I assume you have somehow multiple plugins using dmodel as extension

Comment: Please create a new project with file extension abcxyz and use that one

Comment: I only have one plugin that uses this dmodel extension.

Comment: Sry another try. Invoke the command directly your dmodel file not the c file. Alternatively give me everything I need to reproduce

Comment: Btw you may have a look at https://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/xtext-calling-the-generator-from-a-context-menu/ as well

Comment: So I am trying to hardcode a uri path
                URI uri = URI.createURI("/Users/Desktop/blog.mydsl");
in my original code

but now 
            IResourceSetProvider rs1 = IResourceServiceProvider.Registry.INSTANCE.getResourceServiceProvider(uri).get(IResourceSetProvider.class);
            ResourceSet rs =  rs1.getInstance(ResourceSet.class);

            Resource r = rs.getResource(uri, true);

results in a null for no such resource. I guess the problem with my code is either the injector (in this case), or the URI, and I am trying to debug this

any suggestions?

Comment: No in Ui hard platform:/resource/myproject/path/file.mydsl and ask the iredourcesetprovider for a resourceset for your myproject

Comment: Ps did you try my blog. Example?

Comment: I am trying it, I did change the URI to point to a file outside of eclipse and it is working with the code above. Thus, I think the URI is the problem here

Comment: as said. i can only help if i can reproduce

Comment: yes I understand, I am just updating.
At the moment I am looking into it, and also into traversing the EObject